# Printing the items from a list with the index value of another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists, one with destinations and one with the cost you would need to go to said place.

What I need to do is for example, if the user chooses `"7500"` all of the places that cost `"7500"` will show. As you can see in the code below `"7500"` is repeated twice, so I would need the two destinations that have that price.

I already have the code to find the points needed, but I have no idea on how to continue with printing the destinations that go with those points.

```
destinations = ["Toronto", "Winnipeg", "London", "Ottawa","Miami", "Edmonton"]
pointCosts = [7500, 9000, 11000, 7500, 9500, 9000]

def CheapPoint (pointCosts):
    lowest = [0]
    for x in pointCosts:
        if x < lowest:
            lowest = x
```

For example, for output I would like something like:

`Points: 7500`
`City: Toronto`
`City: Ottawa`

As of right now I only get the points, but I would also like to get the destinations, also I cannot use any built-in functions.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code to get the points?

Comment: `zip` the two lists, then simply `filter` them or use a list comprehension.

Comment: `[city for city, cost in zip(destinations, pointCosts) if cost <= selectedPoints]`

Comment: in your code lowest should not be initialized with `[0]` (a list), but with a large number, e.g. `lowest = 1000000000`

Answer (score 2):

```
score = 7500

example = [ x for x, y in zip(destinations, pointCosts) if y == score ]
```

output

```
['Toronto', 'Ottawa']
```

you can print on separate lines by print() function:

```
print(*example, sep = '\n')
```

output:

```
Toronto
Ottawa
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Is there a way I could print them on separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a dictionary instead of two separate lists?
e.g: 
`locations = {"Toronto":7500, "Winnipeg":9000 ...}`

```
points = 7500
for destination,pointCost in locations.items():
    if pointCost == points:
        print (destination)
```

You can then iterate through the dictionary to pull out aggregations of keys

Answer (score 0):

`[ print(y,x) for x, y in zip(destinations, pointCosts) if y == 7500]`

> 7500, 'Toronto',
>
> 7500, 'Ottawa'